# Is there an equivalent for DropwizardTestSupport in Micronaut?

Tags: java, integration-testing, dropwizard, micronaut

I'd like to run my application with JUnit for the integration test.

For Dropwizard, I've been using DropwizardTestSupport library to achieve that.

Wondering if there's an equivalent for that in Micronaut.

Thanks

Comment: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html#introduction The documentation is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that is the equivalent of `DropwizardTestSupport` because I have not used that but we do have a Micronaut Test library which is described at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html.  In short, you can annotation your test with `@MicronautTest` and that causes useful things to happen including starting up the app and subjecting your test class to dependency injection.

I hope that helps.